# Создание переменной в одной роли ansible и передача значения в другую

Tags: ansible

Можно ли сделать что то наподобие:

```yaml
- name: Getting ip
  hosts: host-0
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Save current ip
      shell:
        cmd: 'echo {{ ansible_host }}'
      register: ansible_old_host

- name: Getting next hosts
  hosts: host-1
  become: true
  roles:
    - tet
```

Сам код роли `tet`:

```yaml
- name: Check configuration vpn
  shell:
    cmd: 'echo "{{ ansible_old_host }}"'
  register: debug

- debug:
    msg: "{{ debug }}"
```

Идея состоит в том получить ip из одного хоста, и передать значение в другой плейбук. Можно ли такое реализовать без использования файлов т.е. 'на лету'?

Answer (score 2):

Решил данную задачу с помощью параметра `delegate_to` . С помощью данного параметра можно выполнять команду на другом хосте в рамках одного плейбука. Это же касается и переменных которые необходимо передать на другой хост